# Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive real numbers that satisfy
$$2 \log_x (2y) = 2 \log_{2x} (4z) = \log_{2x^4} (8yz) \neq 0.$$
The value of $xy^5 z$ can be expressed in the form $\frac{1}{2^{p/q}}$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $p + q$.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: So far now I have $\sqrt{x^a}=2y$ and $\sqrt{(2x)^a}=4z$, but I don't know how to use this to get $xy^5z.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$2 \log_x (2y) = 2 \log_{2x} (4z) = \log_{2x^4} (8yz) =k$$
$$\implies 2y=x^\frac{k}{2}$$
$$4z=(2x)^\frac{k}{2}$$
$$4z=2^\frac{k}{2}.x^\frac{k}{2}$$ 
$$2z=2^\frac{k}{2}.y$$

Comment: i got $z=y$....

Comment: i just solved and got that